# How do i generate a pair of random values relative to an incrementing seed?

Tags: node.js, math

I have a grid with 200 lines and 200 columns.
I want to generate random pairs of coordinates i,j by using a numeric seed. This seed is a value i am incrementing each time I generate a pair of numbers.

After 40,000 values have been generated, all pairs of coordinates are unique amongst themselves, as there is no i,j and m,n where i=m and j=n.

For example:

```
seed 0: generates 43,12
seed 1: generates 154, 62
```

and so forth...

The seed implies the same input with the same function generates the same result, I am fine with that.

I am aware I need some sort of pseudorandom algorithm, as using the computer time or something might generate two identical pairs, but where do I start?

Answer (score 1):

If you want every seed to return a random point, and all of those points to be unique, the easiest way to do it is to put the points in an array, shuffle the array, and then use integer seeds to index the shuffled array.  For example, `seed=0` would get whatever element happened to be shuffled into the first position.

It seems a bit easier to me to let integers represent the pairs, so make an array from 0 to 40000 (ie, 200x200), shuffle this, and then use seeds in the range 0 to 40000.  To convert the integer, `n`, to a point pair use, `i=n%200` and `j=(n-i)/200`.

Of course, since you want each seed to return a unique point, you must have equal or fewer seeds than the number of points,

Comment: This has potential, but I don't want to make a permuted array from 0 to 40k. The seed starts from 0 and its incremented each time a pair is created. If I multiply the seed with a large prime number might do the trick. I will test it tonight and come back with my results.

Comment: I don't think the seed to your RNG is the issue: the random numbers with seeds 0 and 1 should be as uncorrelated as those with seeds 0 and 873391, or whatever.  Instead, your problem is collisions. Think of it like this: you have a box of numbered balls, 0 to 40K. You pick one, write down the number, and throw it back in.  The chance of writing down all numbers before you get the same one twice is astronomically small.  (Just consider you're almost there, and have one left that you haven't written down, the chance of picking exactly this one from the box is 1 in 40K.)

Answer (score -1):

You need a random number generator that you can set the seed value for.  Seems like you're aware of that.  You can't set the seed for `Math.random()` but there's plenty of pseudorandom number generators out there.  I suggest you take a look at [seedrandom.js](http://davidbau.com/archives/2010/01/30/random_seeds_coded_hints_and_quintillions.html).